# Hamiltonian as a matrix and its elements

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian, linear-algebra, matrix-elements

Let us consider an electron in an infinitely deep one-dimensional potential well of thickness L with zero potential energy at the bottom of the well. The normalised eigenfunction solutions to this can be written as the ket vectors $\left|\psi_n\right\rangle$ .

To calculate the matrix elements of the Hamiltonian in this basis, $\left|\psi_n\right\rangle$, in units of $E_1$, the eigenenergy of the $n=1$ state for let us say $H_{11}$, we would see the unit is 1 as,

$$H_{11}=\left\langle\psi_1\right|\hat{H}\left|\psi_1\right\rangle=\left\langle\psi_1\right|E_1\left|\psi_1\right\rangle=E_1\left\langle\psi_1\big|\psi_1\right\rangle=E_1=1 \times E_1$$

The way that I have calculated $H_{11}$ is fairly simple as $E_i=A_{ij}$ which simplifies into an integral where the bra-ket vectors simplify to 1. When it doesn't simplify, such as for $H_{21}$, how would I calculate it with units of $E_{1}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working with an orthonormal basis (you can always choose the eigenbasis of a Hermitian operator to be orthonormal, and eigenstates associated with different eigenvalues are always orthogonal), you'll have $\langle \psi_1 | \psi_2 \rangle = 0$. Hence, $H_{21} = 0$.

Notice this just means the matrix $H_{ij}$ is diagonal when expressed in terms of its eigenbasis.

In a bit more detail,
$$H_{21}=\left\langle\psi_2\right|\hat{H}\left|\psi_1\right\rangle=\left\langle\psi_2\right|E_1\left|\psi_1\right\rangle=E_1\left\langle\psi_2\big|\psi_1\right\rangle= 0.$$

For an example of another diagonal element,
$$H_{66}=\left\langle\psi_6\right|\hat{H}\left|\psi_6\right\rangle=\left\langle\psi_6\right|E_6\left|\psi_6\right\rangle=E_6\left\langle\psi_6\big|\psi_6\right\rangle= E_6 \times 1 = E_6 = 36 E_1.$$
The last equality only holds for the infinite square well. The remaining pieces of the calculation work for way more general systems.

Comment: Thank you so much Nickolas, one more question. So then with anything in the form 2,3 or 3,5 will be 0. How about 6 and 6? 1⟨6∣∣6⟩?

Comment: @ludwigvan $\left\langle\psi_6\big|\psi_6\right\rangle= 1$ from the normalization condition, but I don't see how $E_1 \left\langle\psi_6\big|\psi_6\right\rangle$ would occur in a calculation like this. Instead, $H_{66}$ would read $E_6 \left\langle\psi_6\big|\psi_6\right\rangle = E_6$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be 36 though as $H_{66}=\left\langle\psi_6\right|\hat{H}\left|\psi_6\right\rangle=\left\langle\psi_6\right|E_6\left|\psi_6\right\rangle=E_6\left\langle\psi_6\big|\psi_6\right\rangle=6^2 \times E_1 \times 1=36 \times E_1$ ?

Comment: @ludwigvan Both expressions are correct. $H_{66} = E_6 = 36 E_1$. Of course, this happens for the specific case of a particle in an infinite square well, and might be different for other systems.

Comment: @ludwigvan See the edit in my answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I appreciate it, it makes sense now. Thank you.